# Get double value from query result

Tags: c#, sql-server

I call a store procedure in C# the results are:

```
0.033333
0.550000
0.133333
24.133333
```

In my c# code I need to check which one is high than 24. How can I get double convert the query result to do that?

Here's my code:

```
sqlConnection con2 = conec.ObtenerCon();
SqlCommand com2 = new SqlCommand("ind_meta", con2);
com2.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
com2.Parameters.Add("@finicial", SqlDbType.DateTime);
com2.Parameters["@finicial"].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(fini + " " + hini);
com2.Parameters.Add("@ffinal", SqlDbType.DateTime);
com2.Parameters["@ffinal"].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(ffin + " " + hfin);

DataTable ds1 = new DataTable();

using (SqlDataAdapter a1 = new SqlDataAdapter(com2))
{
   a1.Fill(ds1);
}                               

foreach (DataRow dsRow1 in ds1.Rows)
{
  if (double.Parse(dsRow1[0].ToString(), NumberStyles.Currency) < 24)
           a++;
  if (double.Parse(dsRow1[0].ToString(), NumberStyles.Currency) > 24 &&  
 double.Parse(dsRow1.ToString(), NumberStyles.Currency) < 48)
           b++;
 if (double.Parse(dsRow1[0].ToString(), NumberStyles.Currency) > 48)
   c++;
}
```

Comment: Why do you parse strings if you could cast it directly to `double`? For example: `double value = dsRow1.Field<double>(0)`

Comment: My guess is your code is not doing what you want it to do? What *is* it doing? Any errors reported? Output different from what you are expecting? What is the problem?

Comment: It doesn't work the error is about convert, the result of the query that recive is: datediff(date1,date2)/60.

Comment: Tim's code should work. Please post the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you don't convert your double value to string in the database, so you don't need to convert it to string in C# neither. You just have to cast it accordingly.

```
double value = dsRow1.Field<double>(0);
```

So the complete loop:

```
foreach (DataRow dsRow1 in ds1.Rows)
{
    double value = dsRow1.Field<double>(0);
    if (value < 24)
        a++;
    else if (value >= 24 && value < 48)
        b++;
    else
        c++;
}
```

**Edit**: "*It doesn't work the error is about convert, the query  is: datediff(date1,date2)/60*"

[`DATEDIFF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) has three arguments, so your code would  even cause a syntax error. But i assume that you are using it with the `datepart` argument, for example the hours:

```
DATEDIFF(hh, date1,date2)/60
```

This is an integer division since `DATEDIFF` returns a signed integer. Integer divisions always result in an integer, the decimal part is truncated. You need to cast one side to a floating point number:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(mi, GetDate(),DATEADD(dd,1,GetDate())) / CAST(60 AS DECIMAL(9,2))
```

Now you can cast it to `decimal`:

```
foreach (DataRow dsRow1 in ds1.Rows)
{
    decimal value = dsRow1.Field<decimal>(0);
    if (value < 24)
        a++;
    else if (value >= 24 && value < 48)
        b++;
    else
        c++;
}
```

However, why do you need to divide through 60 at all? That sounds as if you want to get the hours from minutes. Then you could use the correct `datepart` in the first place:

```
DATEDIFF(hh, GetDate(),DATEADD(dd,1,GetDate()))
```

Comment: It doesn't work the error is about convert, the result of the query that recive is: datediff(date1,date2)/60

Comment: I divide through 60 becouse i need to know hours and minutos but all together, example 8:30 = 8.50